# Year as column name, after melting it became factor, and can not be plotted in the right way

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I used melt function in R. In my original dataset, year is the column names (2000-2010).

```
    try1 <- melt(<original dataset name>,id = c('Country.Name', 'Indicator.Name'))
```

After I melt it, the dataset is as follows

```
    Country.Name Indicator.Name                           variable  value
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2000      94.45697
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2001      96.01653
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2002      96.65300
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2003      96.98010
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2004      96.76511
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2005      97.09351
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2006      97.59431 
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2007      98.12538
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2008      98.52662
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2009      98.85694
    Brazil        Access to electricity (% of population) 2010      99.16006
```

However, when I check the class of each variable:

```
    str(try1)
    data.frame':    11 obs. of  4 variables:
    $ Country.Name  : chr  "Brazil" "Brazil" "Brazil" "Brazil" ...
    $ Indicator.Name: chr  "Access to electricity (% of population)" "Access 
    to electricity (% of population)" "Access to electricity (% of 
    population)" "Access to electricity (% of population)" ...
    $ variable      : Factor w/ 11 levels "2000","2001",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
    9 10 ...
    $ value         : num  94.5 96 96.7 97 96.8 ...
```

I want to draw the graph of the indicator value in each year as follows；

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    p <- ggplot(try1, aes(x = as.numeric(levels(variable))[variable], y = 
         value)) + 
         geom_point() +
         geom_line() +
         labs(title = try1$Indicator.Name[1], x = 'year', y = '%') +
         theme_economist()
   ggplotly(p)
```

but the year value in the graph is not correct, it showed 2000.0,2002.5,2005.0,2007.5,2010.0 in x-axis.

However, when I checked

```
    as.numeric(levels(try1$variable))[try1$variable]
    [1] 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
```

I also tried as.numeric(as.character(variable)), or added variable.factor = FALSE within melt, it doesn't help.

Where did I make mistake, and how to correct it? Thanks

Comment: try `x = factor(variable)` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(ggthemes)

p <- ggplot(try1, aes(x = as.factor(variable), y = as.factor(value)))  + 
     geom_point() +
     geom_line() +
     labs(title = try1$Indicator.Name[1], x = 'year', y = '%') +
     theme_economist()

ggplotly(p)
```

Hope this helps!